# Some cells are invisible in Pivot table

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table

I am using a form with 2 sub forms in an Access application.

The problem is as soon as I try to do something like

```
Me.Requery
Me.Refresh
```

it just screws up the display for no reason whatsoever.
I searched for a bit and some answers were to do a

```
form.repaint
```

after re-querying but that didn't work.

Is there a valid reason for why this happens? *Screenshots*

[image: After form is loaded]

After Requery:

[image: After pressing 'Refresh Data' button which only does Me.Requery]

I get

1) Empty Cells

2) Wk numbers (x-axis) get compressed into very little space resulting in what i think is truncation (the - that appears)

3)Even more silly is that data could be shown by highlighting(clicking and dragging) some cells but at the same time it shows hidden cells and hides shown cells.

4) Code in y-axis is empty

Bigger Screenshots if you need at:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWu90.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNs91.jpg)

Comment: Could you show SQL of your query?

Comment: The SQL for the affected subform:
SELECT * FROM QSpacePerWeek1_Local;
Which is a local table the data inside that table gets recreated only at the launch of the main form (and i've disabled the creation in order to test)

Comment: Just in case:
INSERT INTO QSpacePerWeek1_Local
SELECT *
FROM QSpacePerWeek1;

which comes from SELECT CID2, TrialID, CultureStepID, TrialCode, Action, locationCap, culturestep, m2, wk, EntryVarNr, code, step, availableSpace, Site, Code3, cropspecialist, requestor, actualStartyear, dummy
FROM QSpacePerWeek1_View
WHERE (((wk)>=[forms]![FormLocationPlanning]![minWeek] And (wk)<=[forms]![FormLocationPlanning]![maxWeek]));

and QSpacePerWeek1_View is a view on the SQL server